# What's the typical part to be added to the User Requirements Document?

Tags: specifications, requirements

I am writing a *user requirements document* for a standalone application.
The application is supposed to help to look for files on archives.
I have the following structure of the document :

- Introduction
- Functional needs  .

  - Functionals of the system
  - UI
- Non functional needs

is it sufficient ? Do you know other parts that I can add ? Do I write "Project management timing" ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following structure:

1. Introduction -
   including Executive Summary, General Assumptions & Design Guidelines, Prioritization guidelines, Purpose of Document
2. The product personas
3. The product domains
4. The product interfaces (possible external and internal)
5. Supported scenarios and End to End flows.
6. Functional requirements
7. Security considerations.
8. Non functional requirements - including performance, scalability, resilience